# How to speed up Jest Tests?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jestjs

It takes a very long time (about 15 seconds) for me to run a suite of about 10 tests using Jest and React Testing Library, kicked off through Intellij Ultimate (Webstorm)

But when I look at the test results pane, it looks like almost all of that time (like 14 seconds) is spent simply setting up the test environment, loading the libraries, etc.

Then it blazes through all 10 tests lightning fast, in less than a second.

Obviously we don't want to spend so much time re-configuring every time, if we are writing tests with minor changes in between.

Isn't there a way to configure this so that after the configuration/loading stage, we can simply repeat the step of editing the test file and rerunning, without having to start over with every change?

Comment: Are you testing where the tests exit every time, meaning that once you make a change you are manually re-running the tests?  If so, then what you probably want is to run in "watch mode" with `jest --watch` or `jest --watchAll` -- [you can find out more about "watch mode" in the jest CLI options reference](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli).

Comment: Ok yes "watch mode" sounds like just what I need.  I updated the config file with -watch, but I still can't figure out how to retrigger the test to rerun inside Intellij webstorm

Comment: So, in watch mode, when run from the terminal, it will detect any changes in files and re-run salient tests -- it tends to be intelligent about knowing if the file you changed is imported by other files, and running _all_ related tests.  You can also trigger a re-run by pressing enter, or press '`w`' to get more options such as toggling between running all tests vs affected tests, only failed tests, etc.  As to how this integrates into IntelliJ, I"m not sure-- you may want to add that tag to your question if that is a critical component of what you are asking.